# Adding Icons to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to add Icons to my `NavigationDrawer`.

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/ic_action</item>
</string-array>
```

FragmentDrawer.java

```
private static Integer[] icons = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // drawer labels
    icons = getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
}
```

In my code above, I'm trying to load the xml's array to icons' array, but I got an error that says

```
 "Incompatible types required "java.lang.Integer[]" found "int[]" on getActivity().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons).
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `private static Integer[] icons = null;` to `private static int[] icons = null;`?

As an aside, that field does not need to be static particularly if you are always setting it in `onCreate`.